# Is a shadow 2D?

Tags: optics, geometry, spacetime-dimensions, shadow

I had always thought anything below third dimensions couldn't exist in our 3rd-dimensional world. Correct me if I'm wrong but anything 0d 1d or 2d is massless and also can't have energy so it just can't exist. However, A shadow is the lack of information lack of photons to be exact so they have no energy no mass but, still "show an object".

So my exact question is a shadow actually two dimensional?

Would the surface you cast the shadow onto have to be perfectly flat?

Comment: Weird question. Shadows aren't physical objects, so they don't have to be 3D. Similarly a mathematical point x = 1 y = 2 is 0-dimensional.

Comment: what if String Theory is right and we have more than 3 dimensions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are asking about is just the cross section of a shadow. The shadow itself is a 3-D volume in which light from a source is blocked by an obstacle.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow for more details.

The question of whether anything with less than three dimensions can actually exist in a 3-D world seems more philosophical than physical. Does the flat surface of an absolutely still, small body of water actually exist?

Answer (score 4):

A shadow is simply a partial absence of light.  Less light is hitting the shadowed portion of the surface than its surroundings.  If one is only looking at the surface where there is less light, the shadow is two dimensional (it is measured in two dimensions), if one is looking at the entire space with less light it is three dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

I shadow is just that some part of the ground is reflecting off less light than the rest. It isn't a physical object. The question might rise because in common language we 'unscientifically' refer it to as some noun.
You would always need  a 2d screen for a 3d object.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that shadow can be 3d object also. Take a shadow cast on a partially transparent object e.g. water. Then the lack of light extends some distance into the water giving it a 3d shape.